# OracleSolaris how to

Tags: solaris, ntfs, sunstudio

All,
I just installed OracleSolaris on my desktop and have 2 questions about it:

1. This is a dual boot system with Windows 7. What do I need to do in order for those systems to see each other? I googled "OpenSolaris ntfs mount" but it looks like the 2 packages that people refer to are dead: FSWpart and FSWfsmisc. Is there a solution to do that from Windows 7? Samba is not an option as I need access on the same machine.
2. Also I downloaded SunStudio latest version and according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21988/gemyt.html#scrolltoc), I need to run "solarisstudio.sh". Problem is there is no such file in the archive. What do I do?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What files are in the archive ?

Comment: @jlliagre, I posted the files here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10642517#10642517. Its hard to post such a reply here on stackoverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1: Create a third partition with a fat32 filesystem. Both OSes will access it natively.
There is no reliable ntfs support (I'm aware of) with Solaris and no ZFS support at all with Windows.

2: you downloaded the tarball, not the packaged version which is what the documentation you are looking at is about. Just run something like:

```
bunzip2 < SolarisStudio12.3-solaris-x86-bin.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
mv solarisstudio12.3 /opt
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin
```

and you are done.